# How to decode unicode to get Emoji/Smiley in android Edittext?

Tags: android, unicode, decode, emoji

When i fetch the smiley from edittext then there is need to make its Unicode to send it on server. I got Unicode by using below code :

```
public static String escapeJavaString(String st)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
             char c = st.charAt(i);
             if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && !Character.isSpaceChar(c)&& !Character.isWhitespace(c) ){
                 String unicode = String.valueOf(c);
                 int code = (int)c;
                 if(!(code >= 0 && code <= 255)){
                     unicode = "\\\\u"+Integer.toHexString(c);
                 }
                 builder.append(unicode);
             }
             else{
                 builder.append(c);
             }
        }
        Log.i("Unicode Block", builder.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I got the output as **`'\ud83d\ude12'`** , then send it to server. On receiving side, i got the same from server but when placed it in EditText then it'll shows Unicode in text form same as above output, Doesn't get emoji. How it will decode it to show emoji instead of Unicode in EditText ??

Anybody, have an idea??

Comment: Have you tried encoding that resulting string at all?

Comment: yes i got above unicode by using escapeJavaString mathod as discussed in question.. but unable to decode or convert to smiley again from server

Answer (score 4):

**I got solution** of my above question. call following method as message.setText(unescapeJava(your_string));  to Decode or unescape unicode to smiley in Edittext

```
public static String unescapeJava(String escaped) {

    if (escaped.indexOf("\\u") == -1)
        return escaped;

    String processed = "";

    int position = escaped.indexOf("\\u");
    while (position != -1) {
        if (position != 0)
            processed += escaped.substring(0, position);
        String token = escaped.substring(position + 2, position + 6);
        escaped = escaped.substring(position + 6);
        processed += (char) Integer.parseInt(token, 16);
        position = escaped.indexOf("\\u");
    }
    processed += escaped;

    return processed;
}
```

Comment: Great... You are awesome. Please accept your answer.

Comment: It doesn't require an extra library and works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) **OR** [See example](http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-show-html-string-in-android-textview-webview)

Try this

```
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("\ud83d\ude12"));
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml doesn't work in my case, because i got unicode \ud83d\ude12 from server. But if i print static or particular unicode as u write above then it will show as smiley only.

Comment: Ohk, can you tell me how you display that unicode ?